# Samba ADS Member stopped working. How to find the cause?

Tags: ads, samba

I'm desperate. 
I have a samba 4.1.18 server on OpenSuse 13.2 as ADS domain member with one share. 
The configuration is pretty much like in the samba wiki: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setup_a_Samba_AD_Member_Server
Everything was working fine when 20 days ago suddenly the share could no longer be accessed. I assume some update.
wbinfo -u returns "Error looking up domain users"
wbinfo -t "checking the trust secret for domain -not available- via RPC calls failed"
getent passwd returns the ads users, but uid:gid is 4294967295:4294967295 for everyone
I find "domain -not available-" suspicious, but /ets/hosts and name resolutions seems to be ok. Same with kerberos.
Any hint what I could do? Wherre should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wbinfo -t and wbinfo -u are working again.
I removed a package named sssd-libwbclient.
I found the hint in this bug report: [https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1233208][1]